# Emoji characters making MySQL crash using Classic ASP

Tags: mysql, unicode, asp-classic, utf-16, emoji

I have an old site where visitors can add their comments. Until now it always worked well, it doesn't have many visitors (it's for a niche audience). It was built in classic ASP and it's using MySQL (now 5.6). It's running on IIS 8.5 and it connects to the DB without DSN.

Whenever someone adds emoji characters to their posts it'll make the IIS service go into some kind of loop using more than 60% of the CPU and never stops.

I do not want to filter these characters out, I think they fit in well with the site's premise, however I did not foresee this issue. When I first set up MySQL I used UTF-16 to make sure my users could write in any language, and I never had issues until now. There are messages in what looks like Japanese and Korean, and I only figured out it was an issue with Emojis when a user told me what he was doing when the site crashed on him.

- All the site's pages/files are saved in Unicode and for all of them the charset is set as "utf-8".
- The database's collation is utf16_unicode_ci and so are the tables'.
- I can insert Emojis into the tables directly from command line or via HeidiSQL, however....
- The server is sending the Emojis as question marks (?).

Here's my connection string:

> Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode
>   Driver};Server=***.***.***.***;User=******;Password=******;Option=3;charset=utf16;

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for something that is not displaying correctly.

Comment: Rick, I tried everything and after a few hours I simply gave up. I wrote a small script in PHP just to test what the VBScript code was doing and as just as I expected it worked flawlessly. So I decided to rewrite the entire site in PHP and move it to an Apache server. I still don't know what exactly was the issue, my best guess is the ODBC driver is the bad guy here.

Comment: Hmmm... I failed to notice "utf16".  I suspect that is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` end-to-end in `MySQL`.

Comment: I did. I tried all possible combinations of character sets that would use 4 bytes. It seems that to this day there is an issue with the ODBC driver. Apparently a bug with this issue has been reported in 2011. I don't think it's been patched yet. If it ever will.

Comment: I have this same problem, I did this very same solution with MySQL and it doesn't help. It looks we're left high and dry on this by the developers. If they were to add utf8mb4 support on their ODBC connector it would be an easy fix.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ODBC.  Could you show us the connect call that is giving trouble?